# How do i make multiple variations of a string in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I made this one code and I was wondering how I can make it more effective with little work.
This is an example of one of the if then else statements I put in:

```
    If lblQuestion.Text = "anti-" Then
        lblCorrectAnswer.Text = "against, opposed to, preventive; used as a prefix"
        If txtPlayersAnswer.Text = "against, opposed to, preventive" Then
            lblRight.Text = "Correct"
        Else
            lblRight.Text = "Wrong!"
        End If
    End If
```

I was wondering if it was possible to make multiple variations for the statement

```
    If txtPlayersAnswer.Text = "against, opposed to, preventive" Then
```

For example: Instead of having to code out each possible variation for that line of code is there a way to make that one line of code have all the possible variations, and if so how?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Too many assumptions of user input for me , but

pseudo code

Given answers was an array of ["against"],["opposed to"],["preventative"]

then you could do something like

```
count = 0;
foreach(answer in answers)
  if txtPlayersAnswer.Contains(answer) count++
```

case sensitive will be an issue as would be answer like "not against"

Me I'd get the user to enter each potential answer separately instead of having to rely on them entering them in a format you knew how to chop up.